# Need help with Rigify in Blender v2.83 not working

Tags: rigging, rigify, meta-objects

Working on a personal project for my class assignment. Set up a Metahuman on my mesh but got below error when I went to Rigify?! This was a stock/default Metahuman from Blender so I can't imagine why it would have an error in generating the rig? Please help as this project is due. Thank you so much!
Per request error reads: RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'spine.004': Cannot correct chain - bone position is disjoint. Incorrect armature for type 'chain_rigs'.
[image: Rigify_Error]

Answer (score 2):

This error happens when you have moved "spine.004". That's the 1st bone of the neck (counting from the bottom). This bone is "loose" and can be moved around. But, to generate the rig it must stay exactly on the chest spine "spine.003".

You can move it back with the help of the `3D Cursor`. Move the cursor to the spine's bone (spine.003, the big one). In `Edit mode`, press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, choose `Cursor to Selected`. Then select spine.004, press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, and choose `Selection to Cursor`. That's it.

[image: Spine example]

Comment: Thanks Blunder. That worked and I've got it meshed and working!! Yahoo!! Now I just have to create my FK/IK mech bones and visual ani controls and I'm home free! Wow! Thank you lifesaver!!