# I Tried To rig the face but there is always error

Tags: modeling, mesh, rigging, rigify, pose-mode

[image]I tried to rig the face, but every time I rig there is error `generation has thrown an exception 'bpy_prop_collection(key) : key *org-temple'Lnot found`, and before that there was also an error about `spine.004` something like that.

I wonder how can I fix this error?

[image]

After this I tried some steps it worked but now when I tried to *Automatic Weights*  my character just everywhere and its very messy, I just want to rig the face and that's all.

[Blender file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mzxifibwwaecu98/character%20face%20rig%20ha2i2i.blend?dl=0)

Comment: 1) you can provide a blend by using any cloud service and put a link to your question 2) it might be a driver error...but without seeing any of your settings ...we can just guess, so we have to wait for your blend file before we can help you really without (!) guessing

Comment: u can check my blend mate , thank you

Comment: The "spine.004" error is a common issue when you have moved the neck bone. Have a look here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/199630/107598.

Comment: i think i fixed the spine.004 but now when i try to automatic weight the body , my body mesh goes everywhere very glitchy i will post a pic in a moment

Comment: Are you trying to combine a Mixamo rig with a Rigify Face Rig? First, you should try this in *Rest Position*. Your Mixamo rig is in *Pose Position*. There are 2 options: 1) there is an add-on from Mixamo for Blender that adds a control rig for the animation rig. Then you can add the Rigify Face rig. Have a look here: https://youtu.be/7WDBqXTAKDg. 2) Retarget the animation from Mixamo to a full Rigify rig with the Expy Kit add-on. Have a look here: https://youtu.be/bMFb2qlEuTU, https://youtu.be/r3RoHNOzj7k and https://youtu.be/ars_rEC3oP8