# i want to ask question about face rig in blender

Tags: rigging, armature, rigid-body-simulation, error, rigify

when i generate rig

RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'spine.004': Cannot connect to non-chain parent rig.
Incorrect armature for type 'chain_rigs'
it is showing about rig3ify

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is unanswerable and was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Risking stating the obvious, only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly you alone know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Describe the issue in detail, add [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) of relevant settings and user interface, with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, editing will automatically queue it for reopening review.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need help with Rigify in Blender v2.83 not working](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/199630/need-help-with-rigify-in-blender-v2-83-not-working)

Comment: This a duplicate of the linked question above. In a nutshell: there are several bones in the meta rig that are not connected but their tail/head need to stay at the same position and overlap. If you move only one bone, then the connection breaks and the generation fails with an error. Use *Lasso* select to move the bones.

Comment: Hi, ROSHAN .. please let us know here, if the dupe+ @Blunder 's comment work for you. If not, please edit your question, giving us a good view of your exact situation, otherwise we don't have enough info to answer you.