# Generate rig error with Rigify (Could not match control node for ORG-cheek_glue.T.L.001)

Tags: rigging, rigify

I get an error when generating rig from metarig regarding face bones. I did move some bones around to fit my character's face and think I have bones all connected correctly.

[image: screenshot of Rigify error]

Seems strange it is just one side of the face with the problem. If you can look at my file you will the error message:

*"RIGIFY ERROR: Bone 'cheek_glue.T.L.001': Could not match control node for ORG-cheek_glue.T.L.001
Incorrect armature for type 'base_generate'"*

[image]

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=DeyLLled" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/DeyLLled/)

Answer (score 0):

The bones are misaligned. You need to fix two things:

- the bones in the middle must be centered (x=0.000) so the X-mirror doesn't mess up your work
- bones that must not be detached must be properly realigned

The Rigify's metarig has several bones that must be aligned to other bones but they are not connected to them. For example the [spine and neck](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/199630/107598). The face has even more of them, like the mouth corner, the corners of the eyes, and all the *glue* bones that came with Blender 3.x. (You get them for your rig if you press the *Upgrade Face Rig* button). It's the light green and purple ones in the screenshot below.

If they are not moved together, they can "fall apart". The balls of the bone (= head and tail) of the respective bones must be in exactly the same place. If this is not the case, you will receive an error message.

I recommend using *Lasso Select* or *Circle Select* to move the head and tail of the bones to keep them together.

Other problem that you should fix first is that the center bones (the grey ones) are actually not in the center as you can see. The metarig is located at (0, 0, 0), so your center bones should be at x = 0.000. Otherwise, the X-mirror will mess up one side of your rig.

For example, the nose must be in centered (x=0.000). You can enter the values in the side panel. (Note that 0.0 is not the same as -0.0 for Blender.) If the nose is in the middle, you can "attach" or align the left and right lip bones correctly.

[image: Rigify layout of the face bones]

In X-ray mode you can see that several bones are not aligned properly. Use the 3D Cursor as described in the [linked question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/199630/107598) to fix them.